# Continual error attempting to use MicroPython with HC-SR04 sensor on Bit:Bot

Tags: python, ultrasonic-sensors

On my Bit:Bot from 4Tronix ([see here])[1](http://4tronix.co.uk/blog/?p=1490)

I have an HC-SR04 ultrasound sensor attached. It uses solely pin15, for both trig and echo.  I am able to use Microsoft MakeCode 'block editor' to get a reading ([image: see attachment]) but am unable to find a working solution for MicroPython.

The closest I've found is this one on GitHub (below), but I just keep getting error message of '-11' scrolling across the Microbit's LED Matrix. I've checked for error code -11 but nothing exists.

```
from microbit import *
class HCSR04:

def __init__(self, tpin=pin15, epin=pin15, spin=pin13):
    self.trigger_pin = tpin
    self.echo_pin = epin
    self.sclk_pin = spin

def distance_mm(self):
    spi.init(baudrate=125000, sclk=self.sclk_pin,
             mosi=self.trigger_pin, miso=self.echo_pin)
    pre = 0
    post = 0
    k = -1
    length = 500
    resp = bytearray(length)
    resp[0] = 0xFF
    spi.write_readinto(resp, resp)
    # find first non zero value
    try:
        i, value = next((ind, v) for ind, v in enumerate(resp) if v)
    except StopIteration:
        i = -1
    if i > 0:
        pre = bin(value).count("1")
        # find first non full high value afterwards
        try:
            k, value = next((ind, v)
                            for ind, v in enumerate(resp[i:length - 2]) if resp[i + ind + 1] == 0)
            post = bin(value).count("1") if k else 0
            k = k + i
        except StopIteration:
            i = -1
    dist= -1 if i < 0 else round((pre + (k - i) * 8. + post) * 8 * 0.172)
    return dist

    sonar = HCSR04()
    while True:
        test = sonar.distance_mm()
        display.scroll(str(test))
        sleep(1000)
```

Please help if you can.

Thanks